# How to compare max min values of one column to another column in Azure Data Fatory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the figure below as mentioned I have two data set and I have created a data flow in azure data factory.
I want to get the max and min date from dataset1 and compare it with dataset2.
As in the below example I have min(date_time) = 11-04-2020 01:17:40 and max(date_time) = 30-06-2020  22:00:00. So the dates which fall between this two max and min will be compared with Event_time column in dataset2 and all the matching dates should be printed as "Y" in Dataset1_Data_available column and non matching should be "N".
Thanks!!

Comment: Is your source .csv file?

Comment: Yes..source is csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

screenshot of my test data flow
[image]

**1.source1 is your Dataset1,setting of 'Aggregate1':**
[image]

[image]

Data preview of 'Aggregate1':
[image]

**2.source2 is your Dataset2,setting of 'Lookup1'(In lookup conditions,please make sure left column value never equal right column value):**
[image]

[image]

Data preview of 'Lookup1':
[image]

**3.use 'DerivedColumn1' to change the value of 'Dataset1_Data_available'**

expression:`iif(greaterOrEqual(Event_time, minDateTime) && lesserOrEqual(Event_time, maxDateTime),'Y','N')`
[image]

Data preview of 'DerivedColumn1'
[image]

**4.You can use 'select' or 'mapping' in sink to delete columns you don't need.Then output the result.**

---

**UPDATE**

I create some test sample data.
Data preview of `sorce1`(expected min Date should be '11-04-2020 01:17:40' and max Date should be '24-07-2020 08:09:02'):
[image]

When we use `min(date_time)` and `max(date_time)` in 'Aggregate1'(min Date:'07-06-2020 04:30:40' max Date:'30-04-2020 00:56:56'):
[image]

When use `min(toTimestamp(substring(date_time, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(date_time, 1,2) + substring(date_time,6,14),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))` and `max(toTimestamp(substring(date_time, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(date_time, 1,2) + substring(date_time,6,14),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'))`(the same as we expected value):
[image]

Comment: Hello Steve..Thanks fo the answer I think most of the things are working for me currently apart from some date I find even if the values are not within the max min range it is coming as Y so need to check why that is happening .One clarification required for your above solution ,can i know why we are dong this  (setting of 'Lookup1'(In lookup conditions,please make sure left column value never equal right column value): Why it should not be equal and what this step is doing?

Comment: This step appends columns from 'Look up stream' to your primary stream('Dataset2').Whether appends is depend on 'Lookup conditions'.So it should not be equal to make sure all rows from your primary stream('Dateset2') can append columns from 'Look up stream'(minDateTime and maxDateTime column).`The values are not within the max min range it is coming as Y` could cause by the compare expression.Can you show me some these 'Event_time' values so that I could test them on my side.

Comment: I have edited the data set and added both data set as you asked. One more issue i am facing while doing aggregate in first dataset with above data min value is coming correct but max value is coming incorrect .It is coming as 923-04-2020  00:56:56 ) but should come as 24-07-2020  08:09:02 according to the dataset.

Comment: You need to transform your time string to timestamp then compare.When you compare time string,it is according to the char at ASCII.Your date format is 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss',so you need to do like this:`toTimestamp(substring(date_time, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(date_time, 1,2) + substring(date_time,6,14),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')`(toTimestamp method not support ’dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss‘ format).If you can change your date format,I suggest you change to 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss', then you just need to use this expression`toTimestamp(date_time,'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')`.

Comment: Hi I feel the expression you have provided some error is there I am getting NULL so I changed the expression 
toTimestamp(substring(date_time, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(date_time, 1,2)+ '-' +substring(date_time,7,19),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss') . but I am getting output now as 2020-04-11 05:32:57 i dont understand even if i have given format as MM-dd-yyyy why the output is coming as yyyy-mm-dd and still max value is coming the same as old not the correct one. Am I doing some mistake.

Comment: I have updated my answer.If you date format like mine,the expression is right.The second argument of toTimestamp() method is your present date format,not your expected date format.The date format of this method's output is always 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'.You can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions).

Comment: I have updated my question which I tried ,the same way you said but i am getting null ans max ,min value. Please check above. Am i doing some mistake

Comment: ok,your date format is 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm',mine is 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'.Please try:`max(toTimestamp(substring(date_time, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(date_time, 1,2) + substring(date_time,6,11),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'))`,`min(toTimestamp(substring(date_time, 4, 2)+'-'+substring(date_time, 1,2) + substring(date_time,6,11),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm'))`.I test on my side and it works.